# store data in tree format R

Tags: r

I want to store data in tree format in r. Is there any package in R that can be used?
Data sample:

```
lat lon ,v1,v2,v3,parent,id
23.9917345,90.4195876,83,3,0,0,1
```

here parent column represent the parent id of the current row

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Is this 'tree format' common in another language that you're trying to replicate in R? Based on the actual data you show, a `data.frame()` would be a logical choice to me, but maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: I mean Tree data structure.

Comment: Yeah that's the (maybe just for me) problem...what is a "Tree data structure"? What properties make a "Tree data structure" different from the rest of the native data structures in R? [Here](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node64.html) is a list of them.

Comment: The R data structure `list` is a tree structure and there is also a `dendrogram` class. (I do agree with Chase that you have not provided enough description or data to allow any productive effort at educating you further.)

Comment: I just did a search on '[r] tree data format` and '[r] tree data structure' and find several on point hits, so I am going to presume you didn't do any searching, and hence the downvote.

Comment: Actually I want to store in such a format where I can save the children of every row. So I thought may be there are any package like java's  DefaultTreeModel

Comment: Maybe another approach would be to show an actual example of how you're trying to set up/use/extract the data. People that don't have experience with java's DefaultTreeModel still won't be able to help you.

Comment: I found a way to solve the problem.I have to traverse the data in decending order until I find the root . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the childrens without looping with `aggregate(id, by=list(parent=parent), paste, collapse=" ")`:

Example:

```
> n <- 30; d <- data.frame(parent=sample(n,n,TRUE), id=1:n, value=runif(n))
> children <- with(d, aggregate(id, by=list(parent=parent), paste, collapse=" "))
> children
   parent        x
1       2       24
2       3 12 20 28
3       4        5
4       7  8 17 18
5       8       29
```

(snipped)

Now you can merge that in the original dataset with this:

```
> names(children) <- c("id", "children")
> merge(d, children, all.x=TRUE)
   id parent       value children
1   1     13 0.319805784     <NA>
2   2     24 0.847229065       24
3   3     21 0.946230816 12 20 28
4   4     12 0.915684833        5
5   5      4 0.754628841     <NA>
```

(snipped)